# Не получаю challenge от Let's Ecncrypt

Tags: ansible, letsencrypt, acme

Написал небольшую роль для автоматизации процесса через Ansible

```
- name: Create a challenge for {{ domain_name }} using a account key from a variable
  community.crypto.acme_certificate:
    terms_agreed: "{{ acme.terms_agreed }}"
    acme_version: "{{ acme.version }}"
    acme_directory: "{{ acme.directory }}"
    account_email: "{{ acme.email }}"
    account_key_src: "{{ letsencrypt.account_key }}"
    csr: "{{ letsencrypt.csrs_dir }}/{{ domain_name }}.csr"
    dest: "{{ letsencrypt.certs_dir }}/{{ domain_name }}.crt"
  register: letsencrypt_challenge
  tags:
    - ssl

- name: print result of letsencrypt_challenge varible
  debug:
    var: letsencrypt_challenge
  tags:
    - ssl
```

То есть эта тот момент когда у Let's Encrypt запрашивается сам challenge для подтверждения владения доменом. И проблема в том, что ранее после этой таски в переменной letsencrypt_challenge была исчерпывающая информация о необходимых с моей стороны действиях для подтверждения всей указанной информации в моем будущем сертификате, и я мог дальше перейти к размещению этой информации в доступном для Let's Ecncrypt месте (в моем случае в DNS-зоне обслуживаемого домена)

И вторая таска в указанном куске кода выводила всегда эту информацию, по этому я знаю что её было много. Сертификат я уже получил используя свою упомянутую роль ansible дважды и сейчас подошло время третий раз получить сертификат.

И теперь сам вопрос. На данный момент ни какого челенджа от сервера Let's Encrypt я не получаю. Всё что выводит вторая таска в консоль показано ниже. То есть там только информация о том, что сертификат закончиться через 12 дней, и все остальные задачи моей роли не отрабатывают соответственно.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "letsencrypt_challenge": {
        "cert_days": 12,
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}
```

Может кто-то помочь разобраться со сложившейся ситуацией. На форуме и новостной ленте самого Let's Encrypt ничего не удалось найти.

Comment: По умолчанию значение remaining_days стоит 10, попробуйте увеличить или подождать пару дней

Comment: Почему-то мне попадалась информация что это значение равно 60. То есть разрешено обновлять сертификат только за 10 дней до окончания и не ранее?

Comment: Обновляйте когда хотите, указав нужное вам значение remaining_days

Comment: Я пробовал разобраться во всей этой фигне, в итоге запилил через "command" + "certbot". Работает для ~10 доменов около года, нареканий нет.

Comment: Действительно когда осталось 9 дней действовать сертификату, то всё прошло успешно. А с remaining_days нужно будет побаловаться ещё. Всем спасибо!